# office.js item.close() and inline replies in outlook

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am looking for a way to programmatically using javascript/office.js close the mail/reply item when there is an inline reply. ( the .close() method works if the Outlook reply is popped out. )

Our add-in has its own side bar and send button which triggers some processing 'before' the actual send is done using code.
In web or popped out reply, we can close the window with .close()

However this does not work for some reason with an inline reply in the current Outlook windows client.

Does anyone know a way around this ?

Microsoft documentation even specifically says that .close() does not work in-line replies.
However I find similar questions from 5 years ago still with no solution to this and wondering what if any work around there is ?
Office.MessageCompose interface

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.